# Automatic software testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I want to learn automatic software testing but I cannot decide what interface I want to use (selenium, TestComplete,...) - so i dont know in what language i want to learn automatized testing. I will be really happy if anyone could tell me what could be the best for a new guy in this problematic.

*btw I just read a book from Ron Patton - Software testing and it basicly tells you what basic problematics of software testing are about. + I read some stuff about c# language too and I can say I know some basic stuff about it.*

Comment: What types of things are you looking to automate? Another way to look at this question is what problem are you hoping to solve through automated testing (checking)? Based on the problem you need to solve, you would then choose a technology (language) or tool that fits your solution.

Comment: Once you understand your goal for automation (automating just for the sake of automating is not a good goal) and choose a language or tool, then you'll need to understand how you'll identify problems with said tool.

Answer (score 2):

Well for Automation testing you go with **Selenium Web-driver** .
Selenium is *open source* functional testing for Web application recently It is mostly used for web automation

1. Start with basics Selenium IDE it is Mozilla Firefox Add ons

   - http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/
2. Selenium web driver with JAVA

   - http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/
   - https://code.google.com/p/selenium/
   - http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/
   - http://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

The xUnit framework is very popular for unit testing and can be utilized in many languages. The junit framework, or Java xUnit implementation is especially widely used. Personally, I think it's a good place to get started with unit testing. I'm partial to Vogella's tutorials for Java in general, and I think his jUnit introduction is pretty good: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, from your description, I think you might not be talking about unit testing, but automatic functional testing. And as you've mentioned selenium and testcomplete, I guess you are going to do automatic web testing for web sites?
If my guess is right, here are my opinions:

1) first of all, know your to-be-tested product well.Not only from technology perspective, but also from business perspective.

2) To learn some fundamental concepts and testing methods will help you to test (you should know how to test before you think about how to automatically test it, right?).There are many good books in this topic.

3) Facing automatic web testing, to know something about html, css, javascript is important. Also know something about your back-end language will help (for example, if your backend system is written by php, then you'd better get some basic ideas about how it works with web pages)

4) For automatic web testing tools, I can only say that selenium is a good tool for our product. But it is up to you to determine whether it fits your product. Just like what @Chris Kenst said in the comment. There is no silver bullet in web testing...

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium WebDriver](http://onpathtesting.com/good-things-come-in-small-packages-selenium-webdriver/) is the most popular automated test framework being used in software development nowadays. Since it supports all the main programming languages such as C#, Perl, Ruby, PHP and JAVA, you have the freedom to learn and create test code in any of these languages. Selenium WebDriver+JAVA is the combination which is used the most. Of course, knowledge of html, javascript and css is important. Keep in mind that a tester's job is hands-on. There will be many good books on test automation. However, the best training and skill set comes from working on actual projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to go with selenium web driver with Test NG automation testing framework, because 
Using TestNG you can generate a proper report, and you can easily come to know how many test cases are passed, failed and skipped.
You can execute failed test case separately. For example.
Suppose, you have five test cases, one method is written for each test case (Assume that the program is written using the main method without using testNG). When you run this program first, three methods are executed successfully, and the fourth method is failed. Then correct the errors present in the fourth method, now you want to run only the fourth method because the first three methods are anyway executed successfully. This is not possible without using TestNG.
The TestNG provides an option, i.e., testing-failed.xml file in the test-output folder. If you want to run only failed test cases means you run this XML file. It will execute only failed test cases.